# Não estou conseguindo editar no CRUD - NodeJS + Express + MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs, express.js

seguinte:

Comecei literalmente hoje a trabalhar com NodeJS + Express + MongoDB e como exercício comecei pelo famoso CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete).

Consegui fazer quase tudo menos a parte de editar, estou realmente "me batendo" para resolver, a um bom tempo e resolvi pedir ajuda.

Código de edição

```
// Editar item
router.put('/edit', function(req, res) {
    var id = req.body.id;
    var title = req.body.title;
    var description = req.body.description;
    model.findById(id, function(error, task) {
        if (error) {
            throw error;
        }
        task.title = title;
        task.description = description;
        task.save(function() {
            res.redirect('/');
        });
    });
});
```

Eu realmente estou tendo problemas para encontrar o erro já que não manjo quase nada dessa sintaxe, que é nova para mim, segue abaixo o form em html (ejs)

```
<form action="/add" method="post">
    <legend>Incluir uma tarefa</legend>
    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Título">
    <textarea name="description" placeholder="Descrição"></textarea>
    <button type="submit">Adicionar</button>
</form>
```

Estou usando o template ejs.

Agradeço quem puder me ajudar!

Comment: como você tem `router.put('/edit', ...`, não deveria ser `<form action="/edit" method="put">`?

Comment: CRUD quer dizer: Create, Read, **Update**, Delete

Comment: @mercador já tentei mas não muda nada, é como se ele não achasse o que estou fazendo no código do Edit pois ele me leva a uma página de erro 404.

Answer (score 0):

a sua rota deveria ser assim

```
router.put('/edit/:id', function(req, res) {
var id = req.params.id;
.......
```

ai no seu form seria assim

```
<form action="/edit/idDaTask" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put" />
```